# Why Am I Getting No instance for (Num (m0 b0)) arising from a use of ‘it’

Tags: haskell, ghc

I am reading "What I Wish I Knew When Learning Haskell", and on page 72 there is this statement:

> The first law is that when `return a` is passed through `(>>=)` into a function `f`, this expression is exactly equivalent to `f`.

So I am trying to do this:

```
return 3 >>= (+ 1)
```

and I get

```
    No instance for (Num (m0 b0)) arising from a use of ‘it’
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `return 3 >>= (+1)` is equivalent to `3+1`, but the type of `3+1` should be a `Monad m => m a`: [**`(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-62--62--61-) requires that the right operand is a function that takes an `a` and returns an `m b`. It thus looks for a way to see this as a `Num`ber, but that does not make much sense.

You can for example work with [**`print :: Show a => a -> IO ()`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:print) to print the result, so:

```
return 3 >>= print . (+1)
```

Comment: I changed my GHCi command to:
```(return 3) >>= (\x -> Just (x + 1))```
and that worked great. Thank you!

Comment: Also tried the code you wrote and it worked nicely too

Comment: `return 3 >>= return . (+1)` works without specifying any particular monad as well. This expression can be refactored into `return ((+1) 3)` or `fmap (+1) (return 3)` as well to get a different perspective on what is happening.

Comment: And you can play around with different monads with each, e.g. `... :: Identity Int` (from `Data.Functor.Identity`), `... :: Maybe Float`, `... :: [Integer]`, etc.